# Avoid stanza indentation in eledpar

Tags: indentation, poetry

I'm typesetting epic verse in parallel text format, i.e. with the original langugage on one page and the translation on the facing page. Having played around with a number of parallel packages, it transpires that the `eledpar` and `eledmac` packages are good for doing this.

However, the implementation isn't entirely perfect for my purposes. Firstly, the `eledpar` package needs you to pre-determine the indentation *every line in the verse* with the `\setstanzaindents` macro. Whilst you can pass more arguments to this macro than there are lines in your verse, this ends up looking ridiculous, especially since I want no indentation on my verse at all. I have experimented with the `\setcounter{stanzaindentrepetition}{9999}` macro and so forth, to no avail.

Really my question is: Is there a simple way in which I can suppress all the indentation in the `astanza` environment, whilst retaining the main useful feature of the `eledpar` package (i.e. facing page parallel texts)?

**MWE:**

---

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{eledmac,eledpar}

\begin{document}

\setstanzaindents{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}

\begin{pages}

\begin{Leftside}

\firstlinenum{2}
\linenumincrement{1}
\beginnumbering

\begin{astanza}
First in first stanza &
Second in first stanza &
Second in first stanza &
Third in first stanza &
Fourth in first stanza &

First in second stanza &
Second in second stanza &
Second in second stanza &
Third in second stanza &
Fourth in second stanza \&
\end{astanza}

\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}

\firstlinenum{2}
\linenumincrement{1}
\beginnumbering

\begin{astanza}
First in first stanza &
Second in first stanza &
Second in first stanza &
Third in first stanza &
Fourth in first stanza &

First in second stanza &
Second in second stanza &
Second in second stanza &
Third in second stanza &
Fourth in second stanza \&
\end{astanza}

\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}

\Pages
\end{pages}
\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT:** I have played around with `\setstanzaindents{0}` and `\setcounter{stanzaindentrepetition}{1}` *ad infinitum* and repeatedly obtain the infuriating response:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   \sza@1@
1.18 \begin{astanza}
```

From the `eledpar` and `eledmac` documentation, this error occurs when stanza indentation is set incorrectly - it's trying to get the indentation length, but no such length has been set (or at least that's my interpretation).

Comment: hmm I get `! Undefined control sequence.
\do #1->\ifvoid \cuse ` on your example (with texlive 2012)

Comment: looking at the source I think you can use `\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}` then just set the indent list to `0` once and it will repeat. (But I can't test as noted in other comment)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This solution initially looked promising, but yields `! Missing number, treated as zero.` errors which I've come to interpret as meaning indents are incorrectly defined.

Comment: I'm curious what the benefit of the `astanza` environment is. Is there a reason not to use the `\stanza` command? Without making the change, I can't even get the MWE to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way is to say

```
\setstanzaindents{1000,0}
\setcounter{stanzaindentrepetition}{1}
```

The first number tells how many repetitions to generate, the rest is the pattern to generate; the counter setting tells the number of lines in the repetition pattern. While the syntax is clumsy, there may be good reasons for the package author to go this way.

[image]